# Video DownloadHelper has now suggested I install Homebrew. Should I?

Tags: macos, firefox, browser-addons, homebrew, xcode

In short, I don’t have a great I.T. background. I would describe myself as above average, for average day to day tasks. I’m not an administrator at work or anything but I know when I have knocked a cable out and where it should go etc…

Basically one of the add-ons that I use with Firefox, [Video DownloadHelper](https://www.downloadhelper.net/install-converter3.php)—not using it for pirating; using it to watch videos later—is now suggesting that I need the Libav series of tools and libraries to be installed and to do that I need to install Homebrew to facilitate this.

I have figured out what I need to do I think but I am just looking for advice.

Is it a big package? I am currently on limited monthly allowances as I am on Mobile Broadband whilst between suppliers. If it is big—it looks like it would need to be - I am assuming?—I will wait until I have my new ISP sorted out. And a bigger bandwidth allowance.

The `sudo` issue when trying to install it; I am assuming that you need to have the `sudo` command being used—don’t have a background with it—to install it and that it is part of the installation script/package for installing Homebrew (as it needs to be owned by the root)?

I have also been told that I may need to have Xcode 4—I’m on Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion)—to ensure that Homebrew runs OK? Is this true? How do I check that I have Xcode installed? I’m figuring there is a terminal command? As I understand it, Xcode is an Apple Developer tool that I can get offline if I need to?

If it comes to it to grab videos I occasionally have brute forced things (e.g. QuickTime, Soundflower, and SoundflowerBed) but I just preferred Video DownloadHelper as it was a cleaner way of getting things (e.g. if you just wanted to save a technical “How to…” so you can watch it as you try and do it etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Shorter answer.

> Is it a big package? I am currently on limited monthly allowances as I
>   am on Mobile Broadband whilst between suppliers. If it is big—it looks
>   like it would need to be - I am assuming?—I will wait until I have my
>   new ISP sorted out. And a bigger bandwidth allowance.

Homebrew itself won’t break your monthly bandwidth allowance. But Xcode *might* blow away your monthly bandwidth allowance if you choose to install it… But you don’t need it.

That’s because nowadays you don’t need a full Xcode install for Homebrew to work. Apple now has accomodations to install developer command line tools (the stuff that will let Homebrew compile code) which take up much less space and are perfect for us normal folks who are not doing Xcode-specific development.

Xcode itself won’t make Homebrew work “better” but it’s far from trivial an install as far as file size goes. Depending on OS and version it weighs in at 3GB to 4GB in size.

So if bandwidth quotas are a concern, then getting Xcode itself installed will be the biggest consumer of that bandwidth. But you really don’t need Xcode for Homebrew nowadays if you can install Apple’s developer command line tools. More details below.

#### Longer answer.

> Basically one of the add-ons that I use with Firefox, [Video
>   DownloadHelper](https://www.downloadhelper.net/install-converter3.php)—not using it for pirating; using it to watch videos
>   later—is now suggesting that I need the Libav series of tools and
>   libraries to be installed and to do that I need to install Homebrew to
>   facilitate this.

Yes, it seems that Libav and Homebrew are required for video conversion part of Video DownloadHelper [as explained here](https://www.downloadhelper.net/install-converter3.php).

> Is it a big package? I am currently on limited monthly allowances as I
>   am on Mobile Broadband whilst between suppliers. If it is big—it looks
>   like it would need to be - I am assuming?—I will wait until I have my
>   new ISP sorted out. And a bigger bandwidth allowance.

While Homebrew *itself* is not that big in file size, Homebrew *requires* some Apple developer command line tools to be installed. There are two choices you can make to install the Apple developer command line tools: Install the full Xcode package or just install the Apple developer command line tools instead.

- **Don’t Install Xcode if Size Matters:** As of my posting this answer, [the latest version of Xcode is 3.59GB in size](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12). All other versions of Xcode are at least 1GB in size and tend to be 3GB to 4GB in size. You really don’t need the full Xcode unless you are doing Mac OS X specific or iOS development
- **Do Install the Apple developer command line tools:** In contrast, the command line tools are about 10x smaller in size. For example, the Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) specific version of the command line tools is about 118MB to download. Much better option for users who need to compile things from the command line manually or via tools like Homebrew than a full blown Xcode install. You can [download the package installer from here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) or you can open up the Terminal and type in this command: `xcode-select --install`. Just choose “Install” (don’t click “Get Xcode”; see picture below) and let the process complete. When done you will have all of the necessary command line tools Homebrew needs to compile from source.

[image]

Now this:

> The `sudo` issue when trying to install it; I am assuming that you
>   need to have the `sudo` command being used—don’t have a background
>   with it—to install it and that it is part of the installation
>   script/package for installing Homebrew (as it needs to be owned by the
>   root)?

Are you an administrator on your local Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) machine? Because all running a command via `sudo` means is you are running it as `root` which means “administrator.” So as long as you are an administrator on your machine and you know your password, you should be good to go.

> I have also been told that I may need to have Xcode 4—I’m on Mac OS X
>   10.8 (Mountain Lion)—to ensure that Homebrew runs OK? Is this true? How do I check that I have Xcode installed? I’m figuring there is a
>   terminal command?

You don’t need a full Xcode install to use Homebrew if you can install the Apple command line tools instead. Xcode won’t make anything work better. All Homebrew does is automate the process of compiling source code in Mac OS X. So without some command line compilers, Homebrew cannot work at all.

That said, generally if you don’t think you have Xcode installed it’s not installed. On earlier version of Mac OS X there would be a `Developer/` directory installed on your hard drive at root level. On more recent versions of Mac OS X—versions 10.9.5 onward—there should be an actual Xcode application (named “Xcode”) in your `Applications/` directory.

> As I understand it, Xcode is an Apple Developer tool that I can get
>   offline if I need to?

Nope. You cannot get it offline unless you can get someone to download it and copy it for you. You need to download it from Apple. Either from the Apple app store. Or you can get it from Apple’s [official Xcode site right here.](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/)

Comment: You can use homebrew without xcode, you can opt to only install the cli tool package (which is much smaller than xcode) or only download bottled formulae which don't require compiling at all.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a big package?

Homebrew is not big, and the bottle for libav is 8.3M according to:

```
wget --spider https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/libav-11.4.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
```

You do need sudo rights to install homebrew in the default location, but thereafter you don’t need sudo to install packages. And you can choose to put homebrew in your home directory and don't need sudo for that.

You only need the command line tools not the full Xcode. [See this answer to read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools) about getting them.

On another note, it is weird—and I’d even say suspicious—that a browser extension is asking you to install libraries for it. I’d personally not trust them because of that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply & apologies for the delay in getting back to you. Have been really busy with work. In terms of the package & libraries, do we have any idea of the size - e.g. 1GB - 2GB?; just have a data cap., I am still having to work with at the moment. Thanks for the notes on sudo and cli tools - it was along the lines of what I was thinking & noted. Re: the actual extension - I don't have too many concerns about it as it has approx. 5,000,000 users. The library thing is only recently however & I know a lot of users doesn't make it safe.

Comment: I checked the download size of the mountain lion bottle for you.